# MySQL запрос. Выборка максимального значения без повторений

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно вывести две строки указанные на изображении (выделены зелеными рамками).
Не подскажите каким должен быть запрос.
Суть в том что бы вывести строки без повторений по столбцам inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id с максимальным значением процентов по полю inw_percent
[image: поля которые должен показать запрос]

Comment: `GROUP BY user_id, obj_id ...`, затем `user_id, obj_id ... MAX(percent)`. Это мы получим максимальный процент по каждой группе и общую информацию по группе. Далее `join` со всей таблицей, где `on got.user_id = t.user_id, got.obj_id = got.obj_id ... got.percent = t.percent`. Так вы получите максимальные значения.

Comment: Знаю что очень не красиво с моей стороны но не могли бы вы составить этот запрос на основе моей таблице? С группировкой и объединениями у меня пока что туговато. Если пришли то что получилось - вообще смеху будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, среди строк с одинаковыми полями `inw_user_id`, `inw_obj_id`, `inw_st_id`, `inw_jt_id` необходимо вывести максимальный процент, то запрос следующий:

```
select
  inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id, max(inw_percent) max_inw_percent
from tbl_stage_inwork 
group by inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id
```

UPD:
Если требуется получить остальные поля, для найденным строк с максимальным процентом, то необходимо использовать оператор `in`.

```
select distinct
  *
from tbl_stage_inwork 
where (inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id, inw_percent) in
    (select
      inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id, max(inw_percent) max_inw_percent
    from tbl_stage_inwork 
    group by inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id)
```

Comment: Да. Это именно то, что было необходимо - всем огромнейшее спасибо!

Comment: @OG. Так вам нужно было лишь основную инфу(общая по группе + max_percent) вывести? Если воспринимать тело вопроса прямо, то ваш вопрос в том, чтобы получить сами строки полностью.

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, вчера понял что ответ мне не подошел, и я борюсь с запросом дальше.

Comment: Может переформулировать вопрос? Нужно вывести целиком строки со всеми столбцами, те которые имеют максимальный процент для полей `inw_user_id`, `inw_obj_id`, `inw_st_id`, `inw_jt_id`?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, что дополнили ответ и переформулировали вопрос. В принципе подходит - поскольку для одной задачи не может быть несколько одинаковых максимальных процентов. Если вдруг то можно будет обыграть по полю `inw_start_datetime` - они всегда будет разным.

Comment: Запрос должен найти строку с максимальным процентом по условию `WHERE` по следующим полям:
`inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id` и вывести данные именно этой строки (с максимальным процентом `inw_percent`) исключив при этом повторения по всем полям участвующим в условии выборки - собственно по вот этим `inw_user_id, inw_obj_id, inw_st_id, inw_jt_id`. Чувствую, что я сново запутанно выразился. Как показано на изображении приложенным к вопросу - там одна лишняя запись.

Comment: Добавил `distinct`, теперь только уникальные записи.